# Reactjs router - this.props.history.push is not rendering URL queries from same path

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a component that uses history.push to navigate URLs.  The problem is that one of the URL paths relies on search parameters in the URL to render parts of the component.  It works fine when the user initially navigates to the url, but when they update it while inside that path it doesn't work.  Heres's an example:

`App.js`

```
<Router>
   <Route path="/jobs" component={Jobs} />
</Router>
```

The url for jobs will contain a job ID, which is used to retrieve the data from the backend - ex:  `/jobs?id=6583ghawo90`.  With that id I make a `get request` inside  `componentDidMount()` of the Jobs component to populate the page.  Inside the Jobs component a user can navigate to a new job, which updates the url through `` this.props.history.push(`/jobs?id=${newjob.id}`) ``.  The problem is, when the user navigates to the updated URL, the component doesn't call `componentDidMount()` therefore doesn't request the new data.  I can fix this by manually calling `this.componentDidMount()`, but this doesn't work if the user hits the back button in their browser.

Is there anything I can do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be using ***componentDidMount*** but [componentDidUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate):

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  // compare previous jobId and current jobId
  // refetch data if needed
}
```

I would suggest you use hooks if you are in the beginning of the development process.